# Make suitable combinations in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on Swiss System tournament table and i've almost reached the point where i could say that for even numbers i've got it to work but there's a still key piece of my algorithm missing. So, what's going on is that i have Players with different properties but for this problem the main three properties are:

```
Player["hasPlayed"] = [] //which contains names of Players whom the Player have played with
Player["canPlay"] = [] //which contains names of Players whom the Player have not played with but could play.
Player["name"] = "" //Pretty self explainatory
```

So now i have six different players left to place in the table and they all have name in canPlay. So for example the Player number three could easily have two names in canPlay and Player number one only one name and so on. Could someone place some thought on that and maybe point me in the right direction. I must mention that it's obvious that one player can't play two games at the same time, so the games must be placed in a manner that there are two different players per game.

Few of my ideas - i've thought on going with a lot of for cycles but it got really messy and didn't result the way i hoped. Then i watched the combinations algorithm, to create different kind of combinations but failed with this idea aswell.

Could someone with bright mind share some light for me in this particular issue? Thanks :)

```
function reastaArray(){
var newArr = jQuery.extend(true,[],playerLst); //see on meie main
var original = jQuery.extend(true,[],playerLst); //see on meie main
var inPlay = []; //siia hakkame lisama
var firstRound = true;
var i = 0;
var count = 0;
while (newArr.length != 0){
    //seni teeme kuni main-is elemente on veel
    count = i;
    hereiam = false;
    if (inPlay.length % 2 == 0){
        inPlay.push(newArr[i]);
        newArr.splice(i,1);
    }
    else{
        //vähemalt teine round: inPlay.length != 0!
        var lastEl = inPlay[inPlay.length-1];
        var element = newArr[i];
        var played = hasPlayed(element,lastEl);
        while (played == true){
            count += 1;
            //alert(count + " = count ja "+newArr.length+" = newArr.length");
            if (count == newArr.length){
                var hereiam = true;
                finalMatch = inPlay[inPlay.length-1];
                inPlay.splice(inPlay.length-1,1);
                lastfromPlay = inPlay[inPlay.length-1];
                inPlay.splice(inPlay.length-1,1);
                secondLastfromPlay = inPlay[inPlay.length-1];
                inPlay.splice(inPlay.length-1,1);
                newArr.push(finalMatch);
                newArr.push(lastfromPlay);
                newArr.push(secondLastfromPlay);
                returner = canPlayFunc(newArr);
                if (returner == true){
                    played = false;
                }
                else{
                    el_one = inPlay[inPlay.length-1];
                    inPlay.splice(inPlay.length-1,1);
                    el_two = inPlay[inPlay.length-1];
                    inPlay.splice(inPlay.length-1,1);
                    newArr.push(el_two);
                    newArr.push(el_one);
                    returner = canPlayFunc(newArr);
                    //Here i'd put the combinationmaker
                    played = false;
                    alert(played);
                    if (returner == true){
                        played = false;
                    }
                    else{
                    }
                }

            }
            else{
                element = newArr[count];
                played = hasPlayed(element,lastEl);
            }
        }
        if (hereiam == false){
        //nüüd teame, et meil on mingi element, millega eelmine element ei ole mänginud
        inPlay.push(element);
        newArr.splice(count,1);
        }


    }
}
return inPlay;
```

}

Comment: Can you also post the algorithm that you already have, please?

Comment: added the whole function